# converting img to greyscale using js faced security error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a fallback for older phones, I can't merely use css, I found a method turning images into greyscale images using js.

http://jsfiddle.net/4uznof97/

```
  var imgObj = document.getElementById('templateBg');

  function gray(imgObj) {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var imgW = imgObj.width;
      var imgH = imgObj.height;
      canvas.width = imgW;
      canvas.height = imgH;

      canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
      var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

      for (var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++) {
          for (var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++) {
              var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
              var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
              imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
              imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
              imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
          }
      }
      canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
      return canvas.toDataURL();
  }
  imgObj.src = gray(imgObj);
```

But I got this error

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Comment: You need to enable cross-origin resource sharing. Check this out http://enable-cors.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as it relates to canvases: Because the canvas contains something that came from a different *origin*, your code can't modify it.

From the [canvas 2D spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#pixel-manipulation):

> The getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh) method must, if the canvas element's origin-clean flag is set to false, throw a SecurityError exception

If you're in control of both origins, you may be able to enable access through [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). (I haven't done that in relation to canvases, though.)

Comment: my js is at a.abc.com, and my image is at b.abc.com, but I got the issue?

Comment: @AaronMusktin: Right: Those are different origins. For something to be the *same* origin, the host, port, and protocol must all match. `a.abc.com` and `b.abc.com` are different hosts.